# google data api for youtube

Tags: java, gdata-api

I'm trying to run the sample program, which comes with Google Data API. I get a runtime error at following line

```
YouTubeService myService = new YouTubeService("gdataSample-YouTube-1");
```

The error is the following:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps
        at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:118)
        at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:100)
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:532)
        at YouTubeReadonlyClient.main(YouTubeReadonlyClient.java:713)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 4 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I tried both Google Data API versions 1.35.0 and 1.35.1, and I get the same error in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the collections library in your class path.

It's in the `gdata/java/deps` directory in the zip file. Include the `google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar` file in your classpath and you should be fine. (You *may* also need `jsr305.jar` - I'm not sure.)

Comment: i tried to download google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar ,from http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/java/deps, but i get a file of only 32 kb when the actual size shown on that site is 535 kb
is there any other location when i can get this file?
Can u mail it to me. my email id is mindedges@gmail.com

Comment: You don't need to download it separately - it's in the GData API zip file.

Answer (score 2):

Three little steps:

- Download the zip file from
  http://www.docjar.com/jar_detail/google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar.html
- Extract the zip file
- Add the jar to your build path.